# How to open a new activity depending on the recyclerview item clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

How do you open a new activity depending on a certain item that you click from the recyclerview list?

For example, if I click list 1 then it will go to activity 1; if I click list 2 it will go to activity 2.

Right now, every time I click an item on the list it goes to the same activity.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                    Model.class,
                    R.layout.row,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    mDbRef
            ) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class));
```

Answer (score 3):

In your onClickListener do something like that:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   int pos = getAdapterPosition());
   if (pos == 1)
      startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity1.class));
   if (pos == 2)
      startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class));
}
```

Comment: Hi, when i write the getAdapterPostion there were errors, do u know why? sorry im really a beginner

Comment: Do `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: Thank you, it helps. if its okay i'll ask more question

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best way to do this is to have the instance of viewholder provide whatever data is backing it.  The data backing it is set in the onBindViewHolder() method of the adapter.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                                    .inflate(R.layout.li_filter_item, parent, false);

    final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (myRecyclerViewListener != null) {
                myRecyclerViewListener.onClick(viewHolder.getData);
            }
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}
```